# R: pairwise.t.test on a long format data frame with missing values, using one command

Tags: r, dataframe, testing, missing-data

I have a data frame on which I want to perform pairwise t-tests in a paired fashion.

The data frame I start with looks like `mydata_long` below. Different `marker` values are recorded over a few different `times` from the same patients (though I don't have the patient column).

So I want to test `time` differences on a per `marker` basis in a paired fashion. For that I do the following.

```
#prepare example data
set.seed(42)
mydata <- data.frame(id=paste0('id',1:40), time=rep(paste0('time',1:4),10),
                     marker1=rnorm(40, mean=10, sd=2), marker2=rnorm(40, mean=3, sd=1.5),
                     marker3=rnorm(40, mean=8, sd=3), marker4=rnorm(40, mean=4, sd=1),
                     marker5=rnorm(40, mean=12, sd=2))
head(mydata)
mydata_long <- reshape2::melt(mydata, id.vars=c("id","time"), variable.name="marker")
head(mydata_long) #starting data frame looks like this
```

This is my starting data:

```
> head(mydata_long) #starting data frame looks like this
   id  time  marker     value
1 id1 time1 marker1 12.741917
2 id2 time2 marker1  8.870604
3 id3 time3 marker1 10.726257
4 id4 time4 marker1 11.265725
5 id5 time1 marker1 10.808537
6 id6 time2 marker1  9.787751
```

Now I calculate the p-values in one call like this:

```
dt_ttest <- data.table::data.table(mydata_long)
adf2 <- as.data.frame(dt_ttest[, stats::na.omit(as.data.frame.table(
  stats::pairwise.t.test(value, time,
                         p.adjust.method="none", pool.sd=FALSE,
                         var.equal=TRUE, paired=TRUE)$p.value,
  responseName="pvalue", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)),
  by=marker])
names(adf2)[2:3] <- paste0("Group_", c("B","A")) #flip groups 1 and 2 (renamed A and B)
adf2
```

My final results look like this, exactly like I want:

```
> head(adf2)
   marker Group_B Group_A    pvalue
1 marker1   time2   time1 0.5412979
2 marker1   time3   time1 0.8442916
3 marker1   time4   time1 0.3387717
4 marker1   time3   time2 0.4074633
5 marker1   time4   time2 0.1518055
6 marker1   time4   time3 0.2204321
```

Till here, everything is correct...

**HOWEVER**, my first question comes here: How does R know what pairs with what in a long format data frame? The way I designed `mydata`, I expect the first 4 times (time1,time2,time3,time4) are one patient, the following 4 times another patient, and so on... Is that the correct way to order the input data, or how does R interpret it?

**AND NOW MY REAL PROBLEM**

In my real world data, I run many times into missing values... SO let's introduce some here:

```
mydata2 <- mydata[which(!(mydata$id %in% c('id4','id25','id30','id32'))), ]
mydata2$marker1[c(2,7,15)] <- NA
mydata2$marker3[c(7,15)] <- NA
mydata2$marker4[c(2,7,20)] <- NA
mydata2$marker5[c(2,7,30)] <- NA
mydata2
mydata_long2 <- stats::na.omit(reshape2::melt(mydata2, id.vars=c("id","time"), variable.name="marker"))
head(mydata_long2) #starting data frame looks like this
```

My starting data is `mydata_long2` now

```
> head(mydata_long2) #starting data frame looks like this
   id  time  marker     value
1 id1 time1 marker1 12.741917
3 id3 time3 marker1 10.726257
4 id5 time1 marker1 10.808537
5 id6 time2 marker1  9.787751
6 id7 time3 marker1 13.023044
8 id9 time1 marker1 14.036847
```

Now I try to run the tests in the same way, but I of course run into the error below:

```
dt_ttest2 <- data.table::data.table(mydata_long2)
adf2 <- as.data.frame(dt_ttest2[, stats::na.omit(as.data.frame.table(
  stats::pairwise.t.test(value, time,
                         p.adjust.method="none", pool.sd=FALSE,
                         var.equal=TRUE, paired=TRUE)$p.value,
  responseName="pvalue", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)),
  by=marker])
names(adf2)[2:3] <- paste0("Group_", c("B","A")) #flip groups 1 and 2 (renamed A and B)
```

> Error in complete.cases(x, y) : not all arguments have the same length

How to do it in this case (without changing much the code)?

Checking the documentation for t.test, it says `Missing values (NAs) and infinite values (Infs) are removed before calculation. If paired = TRUE, length(x) must equal length(y) and an observation pair (x[i], y[i]) is removed if it has at least one NA or Inf value.`

I was hoping this could be solved on the fly... but apparently we have to manually remove those pairs where at least one value is missing... how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your first question, observations are paired simply based on the ordering in the data.  We can replicate the result for the difference between time 2 and time 1 when marker=1 with:

```
x <- mydata_long %>% 
  filter(marker == "marker1" & time == "time1") %>% 
  select(value) %>% 
  pull

y <- mydata_long %>% 
  filter(marker == "marker1" & time == "time2") %>% 
  select(value) %>% 
  pull

t.test(x, y, var.equal=TRUE, paired=TRUE)$p.value
# [1] 0.006764886
```

So, the arrangement of the data governs how the pairing will work.

For the second question, are you committed to doing this all in one shot with `data.table`? If not, the answer would be pretty straightforward - you could loop over the markers and time-pairs to generate the appropriate p-value for the listwise deleted data.

When you make the missing values, you are both deleting observations, which will make the "balanced" data that resulted in equal length pairs of vectors to "unbalanced" that results in non-equal length vectors of paired data which will cause the paired t-test to fail.  This is more problematic than the missing values.  If you had complete (balanced) data, but that contained missing values, then your function above will work.  However, if the vectors are not of equal length, the paired t-test will fail no matter what data wrangling you do.

Comment: Yes so for the main question, my idea was to "balance" the data before feeding it to the data.table function, so I don't have to modify the code much. To balance it, either remove the whole pair with at least one missing value, or add NAs where appropriate... You think this is more difficult than going through a for loop? Thanks!

Comment: Also not sure what you mean by "listwise deleted data", if you can provide a code example